# Making a call to a kernel module function while context saving/restoring using SWAPGS instruction?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, kernel

I'm currently working on a project where a function "A" inside the linux kernel makes a call to another function "B" in a kernel module.

The basic idea was to provide the address of the target function "B" in the kernel module, via a newly-created syscall which writes the received address to a kernel global variable. Function "A" reads this value and makes a call to that address.

Calling function "B" turned out to be a success, as we verified by inserting a bunch of printk's at the prolog of the function "B".

But the system freezes a while after function "B" is called, presumably because only the control flow is transferred from the kernel to the kernel module so all the other context (stack frame, etc) remains the same as it was in the kernel function "A"

By going through some references, I wrote some x86_64 asm code that should save/restore the context.

```
    .macro SAVE
        swapgs
        mov (old_rsp), %r11
        mov %rsp,%gs:(%r11)
        mov (kernel_stack), %r11
        mov %gs:(%r11),%rsp
        sti

        sub $0x50,%rsp
        mov 0x50(%rsp),%rcx
        mov 0x48(%rsp),%rbx
        mov (%rsp),%r11
        mov 0x8(%rsp),%r10
        mov 0x10(%rsp),%r9
        mov 0x18(%rsp),%r8
        mov 0x20(%rsp),%rax
        mov 0x30(%rsp),%rdx
        mov 0x38(%rsp),%rsi
        mov 0x40(%rsp),%rdi
    .endm

    .macro RESTORE
        cli
        mov %rdi,0x40(%rsp)
        mov %rsi,0x38(%rsp)
        mov %rdx,0x30(%rsp)
        mov %rax,0x20(%rsp)
        mov %r8,0x18(%rsp)
        mov %r9,0x10(%rsp)
        mov %r10,0x8(%rsp)
        mov %r11,(%rsp)
        mov %rbx,0x48(%rsp)
        mov %rcx,0x50(%rsp)

        add $0x50,%rsp
        mov (old_rsp), %r11
        mov %gs:(%r11),%rsp
        jmp *syscall_after_swapgs
    .endm
```

the values old_rsp and kernel_stack are PER_CPU_VAR's in the kernel symbol. (linux 3.14)
SAVE goes right before calling B, and RESTORE comes right after that.
But the system still freezes.

Is there something I'm getting wrong? Or some problem in the code perhaps?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Writing a bunch of code and asking a specific SO question is good, except for the fact that this is all based on your assumption of why the system locked up. Why obfuscate what you're attempting to do? Show your code - "function A" and "function B" may have special calling semantics that you're not following.

Comment: Reading this again, you're allowing userspace to dictate an address that the kernel will call? That is a huge security problem and is a generally bad idea.

Comment: `swapgs` should only ever be used when control is transferred from user-space to kernel space or back (and never used when kernel calls kernel). All of the assembly seems backwards (AT&T syntax but with operands in "Intel syntax order"). Using a global variable for anything is probably a bad idea (race conditions for multi-CPU, etc). Using assembly is also probably a bad idea (your description implies all you need is a boring old function pointer).

Comment: Implementing your own context switching code in the Linux kernel is almost certainly a mistake. If you really need to do this, and I doubt you actually do, you should Linux's own code. You don't actually want to switch the context either. Just modify the other context so that it resumes at kernel code that calls the function and then restores the context to its unmodified state.